# Algorithm to store particle position on a grid (Chaining mesh)

Tags: algorithm, mesh, particles

I have a particle distribution, i.e. a set of 3D array `x`,`y` and `z` that give the positions of N particles. I divide my domain into cells and I would like to program an algorithm which gives me how many particles I have in a cell.
I am looking for something that doesn't use too much memory. If the distribution of particles were mono-dimensional a smart idea is to sort the particles with decreasing `x`. 
In this way we only need to save, for every cell, the particle with smaller `x` within the cell. For example I know that the 7th particle is the particle with the smaller `x` that belong to cell `i`. Therefore, in cell `i`, we have to find particles 0 to 7.

My question is: how can I extend this to 3D? Or, how can I build a chaining mesh?

Comment: The particles have the same mass but different positions. They're confined within a 3D volume, let's say a cube of side 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a trivial problem. You might want to look at [R-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) and indeed [Spatial databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database) in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved much easier.

Make a 3D-array of 'cells'. Loop through your particles and increment value of a cell current particle belongs to.

Sample code:

```
cells = int[X][Y][Z]
for p in particles:
   cx = cast_to_int((p.x / maxX) * X)
   cy = cast_to_int((p.y / maxY) * Y)
   cz = cast_to_int((p.z / maxZ) * Z)
   cells[cx][cy][cz]++
```

*UPD*: works only if all cells have the same correspondent sizes (i.e. x1 = x2 = xn, y1 = y2 = yn...).

Comment: This would be useful to compute the density in each cell, but it's not what I need. I need to know, in every cell, the IDs of the particles that belong to that cell. A dumb way would be saving these IDs in an array, but that would consume a lot of memory. That's why I came up with this chaining mesh idea. If the particles were sorted in a smart way it would be necessary to store only few pieces of information in every cell, and not all the IDs of the particles.